# How to add a Snippet Description in Wagtail

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have been searching in the wagtail documentation and stack overflow to find the answer to my question to no avail. I am currently creating vehicle models using wagtail snippets but in the documentation they have a screenshot that shows their snippets have descriptions next to their titles.

[image]

Does anyone know how to add descriptions to the snippets? I assume it goes in the Meta class in the model however I cant find the value I need to set the description to.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The link to the documentation where I found the image is here: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.9.3/editor_manual/documents_images_snippets/snippets.html?highlight=snippets 
Thats one reason Im quite confused why there is no documentation on it when the photo is in the documentation itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screenshot in the documentation is old (from 2015), and the admin templates and structure of snippets have changed quite a bit since then. The functionality to display descriptions was [removed in this commit](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/commit/fff4568df7be262453a170d2dac0dfc9aca37b8e#diff-1505e2c020d28cedcddba746212f7525) in 2015.

So the short answer is that it's not possible to easily replicate this behaviour. If you really wanted to you could override the [template](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/f3f932d2e52268d4cfaa5e6b3940651b23522484/wagtail/snippets/templates/wagtailsnippets/snippets/index.html) that is used to render the list of snippet models, and add the description yourself - e.g. by looking for a particular property on the `model_opts` (the model meta class) and rendering that.

Comment: Well thats abit dissapointing. Suprised they dont have it menitioned somewhere that the screenshot is not a upto date screenshot when its on the new documentation as well. Thanks for clearing that up though. It explains why I couldnt find anything about it when I was looking.

Comment: Might be worth creating an issue for it on Github!